# Python mysql memory leak in insertion

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, memory-leaks, mysql-connector-python

I'm inserting millions of rows in MySQL using Python3 but I found the memory usage keeps growing and finally reached 64GB. I tried to diagnose the problem and here is a reproduction of the problem: say I have 100 CSV files. Each file contains 50000 rows and I want to insert them into the database. Here is a sample code:

```
import mysql.connector

insert_sql = ("INSERT INTO table (Value) VALUES (%s)")

for i in range(100):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', database='database')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    # Insert 50000 rows here
    for j in range(50000):
        cursor.execute(insert_sql, (j,))
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
    print('Finished processing one file')

print('All done')
```

The database contains only 1 table with 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```

Environment: Mac OS Sierra; Python 3.6.x; MySQL 8.0.1; mysql-connector-python 8.0.11

I understand the memory should grow before committing because the changes are buffered. But I supposed it will decrease after the committing. However, **it doesn't**. Since in my real application I have thousands of files with 100MB each, my memory will blow up.

Did I do anything wrong here? (I'm new to database) How can I keep the memory usage under control? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Edit: I also tried the following code according to the comments and answers but it still doesn't work:

```
import mysql.connector    
insert_sql = ("INSERT INTO table (Value) VALUES (%s)")    
for i in range(100):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', database='database')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    params = [(j,) for j in range(50000)]
    # If I don't excute the following insertion, the memory is stable.
    cnx.executemany(insert_sql, params)
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    del cursor
    cnx.close()
    del cnx
    print('Finished processing one file')    
print('All done')
```

Comment: Have you tried `executemany()` instead of many `execute()` in loop?

Comment: Also Try to use `?` intead of `%s`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, I tried to put all parameters into one list and use `executemany()` to insert them but the memory still keeps growing.

Comment: @RedEyed Thanks but I tried `?`, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try batch execution, this loop of inserts might be the problem.

You can do **executemany**:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO table (Value) VALUES (%s)",
    [('a'),('b')])
```

or big insert statement with all the values you want at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried to put all values in one list and use `executemany()` once for a file, but it doesn't work either. The memory growth still doesn't stop after I close the connection.

Comment: Is it the problem with `sql` object or with list that you pass? Try to make `del cnx

Comment: @RedEyed I think the problem is with `sql` because if I only generate the list with 50000 elements but not use the `executemany()`, the memory usage is stable. I also tried the `del cursor` and `del cnx` after `close()` but they still don't work.

Comment: It seems that there is a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79887)

Comment: @RedEyed Thank you for your response. I don't think this is due to the reported problem because I inserted an integer, not a Unicode string. But I just reported this problem to MySQL in case it is really a bug.